# Erroneous PyDev Errors with Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev, django-1.8

I'm working with Eclipse + PyDev.  I just switched this machine from Django 1.6 to 1.8.  Under Django 1.6, the project had no errors.  Now, under Django 1.8, references to properties of `.objects` on my database model, such as

```
DatabaseModel.objects.filter(...)
```

give me the error

```
Undefined variable from import: filter
```

These errors don't occur in models.py; only if I import DatabaseModel into a different module and call a method of it's `.objects` property from a different module.

How do I get Eclipse to stop reporting these errors?

---

More details:

Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Pydev Version: 3.9.2

I experienced a similar problem when upgrading to django 1.7 (which is why I kept around a version of django 1.6 in my development environment).

Comment: Try adding directory PYTHONPATH by left clicking project->Properties->PyDev - PYTHONPATH->add source folder

Comment: @Wallace To clarify, Django is on my PyDev PYTHONPATH.  PyDev can resolve and follow django imports without issue.  It's just the `.object` methods that are misflagged as errors.

Comment: I'm confused as to the number of close votes on this question.  The PyDev tag alone has over a thousand similar questions.  Moderators, if there is a more appropriate stackexchange site for this question, please suggest this in a comment.

Comment: Why do you think the errors are erroneous? How do you know Django didn't update its library and deprecate stuff or something?

Comment: @Falmarri These are some of the critical methods of django.  They appear in the docs for every version of django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/) and work under the new version of the library.  They also are not flagged as errors in `models.py`; only in other files are they flagged as errors.  The problem is likely that in version 1.7 django changed how they do metaclassing on the Model object, but I don't know how to get eclipse to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Humm, actually let's say that the Django structure is pretty difficult thing to understand, so, the PyDev static analyzer has some hard-coded tricks for dealing with Django... probably they changed that on 1.8, so, the static analysis is not working properly on that anymore (reference: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/src_completions/org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/ModulesManager.java -- method: decorateModule)

Please report this as an issue at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue, but with PyDev 5.0 Django 1.8 no longer suffers this issue, so let's assume it's been fixed :)